# unity build webGL with SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game for web(html5) which connects to a SQLite database to access the game's questions (which I learned in here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html). the database in question is located in a .db file located inside the Assets folder of my project.

When I run it in unity, it connects to the database just right and exctracts the questions. When I build the game, it doesn't. Can anyone help me with this problem? Where should I put my .db file?

Comment: did anybody find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

because You database file is not True Location

Db file would on data folder After The Make Build

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer on Reddit:

> ["Other options you might want to consider are to build a JavaScript
> bridge to something like the browser IndexedDB or WebSQL APIs."](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/bnron8/comment/encklgy/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Personally, how I would approach this is with my WebGL build communicating to a React App it is embedded in. You can use npm package ["React Unity WebGL"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-unity-webgl) then have functions that access [WebSQL database](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/02/using-websql-instead-local-storage-web-app/).

```
const db = openDatabase("my.db", '1.0', "My WebSQL Database", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
useEffect(function () {
   unityContext.on("Create", function (sqlcommand) {
      db.transaction(function (tx) {
         tx.executeSql("data");
      });
   });
   unityContext.on("InsertData", function (sqlcommand, data) {
      db.transaction(function (tx) {
         tx.executeSql(sqlcommand, data);
      });     
   });
   unityContext.on("SelectData", function (sqlcommand, callback) {
      db.transaction(function (tx) {
         tx.executeSql(sqlcommand, [], function(tx, results) {
            if(results.rows.length > 0) {
               for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                  console.log("Result -> " + results.rows.item(i).firstname + " " + results.rows.item(i).lastname);

               }
               unityContext.send("GameController", callback, results);
            }
         });
      });             
   });
}, []);
```

Now you can start using SQL in your WebGL applications.